# why Microsoft.office.interop.word with .net framework 4.5.2 works fine locally but not running on server?

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am working on an application where I make my system to generate a report as word document. For this I've used microsoft.office.interop.word through nuget package manager. It is running fine locally but when I published my changes on server it started showing me below error:

```
     "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied." (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
```

My system admin made some some admin rights related changes on server and instead of this error I started getting below error

```
    Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

after getting this error I checked with server db and was able to generate file locally but not on test server.

Can anybody suggest me something?

Comment: Do you actually have Word installed on the server?

Comment: That com object requires a full office installation on the server. Did you check for that?

Comment: Yes. Server has Office installed on it.

Comment: @RossBush didn't get. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: @NewbieCoder I asked the same question as GSerg.

Comment: You probably should have a look at https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office. On top of explaining why it's not a great idea to have Office on a server, it mentions your error messages too.

Comment: Using `Microsoft.Office.Interop` in a server environment is not officially supported by Microsoft, and is also not recommended as it is very prone to errors (since office is / was never designed for operating on a server side environment). For more information see the following link to the Microsoft Support page: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office

Comment: @NewbieCoder don't use interop to create Word files, especially on the server. `docx` is a zip package containing XML files. You can create docx files with the Open XML SDK or other libraries

Comment: @NewbieCoder it's not that Interop isn't supported, it's simply a bad idea. Each request would have to start a *different* Word instance. On the server. If, for any reason, the code failed to properly close that instance it would remain running. And finally, each interop call is an expensive cross-process call. Generating the same file could easily take 100x times longer than using OpenXML

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for explaining so nicely. Ok I'll try using openXML for this.

Comment: Maybe also note that you don't have to use Office to generate,manipulate office documents,  Our company uses Aspose for a lot of these tasks.  t doesn't require an offices installation on servers!